# Failover Artemis URI in WIldfly 14

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis

Is it possible to configure failover URI for native Artemis server in Wildfly 14? I'd like to create pooled connection factory with url like `(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://localhost:61617)`. As far as I know wildfly creates connection factory from connector host and port. I use Wildfly 14.0.1.Final and Artemis 2.6.3.

**Update**

```
<remote-connector name="remote-artemis-master" socket-binding="remote-artemis-master" />
<remote-connector name="remote-artemis-slave" socket-binding="remote-artemis-slave" />

<pooled-connection-factory
   ha="true"
   name="activemq-ra"
   connectors="remote-artemis-master remote-artemis-slave"
   entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"
   transaction="xa"
   user="user"
   password="password"  />
```

**Update**

When master node stops the slave becomes live but the jee app is unable to send/consume messages 30 for seconds. After this period everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://localhost:61617)` is just a way to configure multiple initial connectors via a URL.  You can accomplish the same thing in Wildfly by defining multiple `remote-connector` elements and referencing those in the `connectors` attribute of the `pooled-connection-factory`.

Comment: It worked indeed but it switches to slave after 30 seconds. What could be the issue?

Comment: What do you mean "switches to slave after 30 seconds"? Please elaborate.  Also, make sure to set the `ha` attributed on the `pooled-connection-factory` to `true` as that will actually enable fail-over if the primary fails.

Comment: Wildfly starts with two connectors - one points artemis master and second points slave. It successfully connects to master and sends/consumes messages. When I turn master off stopping docker container Wildfly does not consume/sends messages any longer. It resumes jms actions exactly 30 seconds after master is stopped.

Comment: I've added current configuration.

Comment: It may simply take 30 seconds for the networking layer to determine there is a problem after you stop the docker container. What happens if you run everything on the same machine/vm/container and use `kill -9 <pid>` to stop the master?

Comment: It works after a couple of seconds. Could you explain what does it mean "networking layer to determine there is a problem after you stop the docker container". What exactly takes so long?

Comment: Like Wildfly instantly sees that it can't connect to master but does not connect to slave either. Slave says it's live just after a couple of seconds but for some reason in docker-compose it takes those 30 seconds.

Comment: The other problem is for some reason when I stop both slave and master and then I'm trying to add something to queue via wildfly app only master can pick up the traffic. Starting slave when master is still down does not handle the messages. In console slave has only cluster-connections without addresses as if it would not be live even though it should cause master is down.

Comment: I'm not a networking expert so I can't really say what takes so long. I've just noticed in my own experience that, for example, using `kill -9` gives different timing results than physically powering off a machine. I would expect manipulating a VM would also give slightly different timing results. Even though all these methods result in the master broker dying the way the various environmental layers (e.g. operating system, network, etc.) handle them is slightly different.

Comment: How a slave acts when it is started without the master also being up depends on the configuration.  Are you using replication or shared-store?

Comment: I'm using replication

Comment: A slave using replication will not fully start if the master isn't also up because the slave doesn't know if it's data is stale or not since the slave could have been shutdown while the master was still alive receiving and dispatching messages. This isn't true when using shared-store because the slave can connect directly to the shared storage device and access the most recent data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182288/discussion-between-julian-rubin-and-justin-bertram).